# Trivial approximation ratio of $n/2$ for 2-Opt for TSP

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, discrete-optimization

I recently read that the 2-Opt algorithm for the TSP yielded an approximation ratio of $n/2$ by trivial reasons. However, there was neither proof nor further context provided and I am curious how this bound can be obtained since I don't see these *trivial reasons*. I hope you can help me and give some intuition of why this ratio holds. (Note: Perhaps this can only obtained easily when considering metric TSP which would totally suffice for my concerns)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your last note. Are you simply looking for a description of the 2-approximation algorithm for metric TSP? In that case you could start here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-2-approximate-using-mst/. Or are you wondering whether there is a 2-approximation algorithm for (general) TSP? Note that the answer is no unless $P = NP$. Let me know if you need more details or pointers.

Comment: @araomis Neither is the case and I am familiar with these. My last note is to clarify that one might need to assume that the distances form a metric to prove the ratio of $n/2$ easily. Since I do not know how to obtain such bound yet, I also don't know if the case with metric TSP simplifies the proof. Does this clarify what I meant?

Comment: So the 2-Opt algorithm yields an approximation ratio of $2$, right? So if $n \geq 4$ you get $n/2 \geq 2$ and hence the same algorithm gives you an approximation ratio of $n/2$. If $n < 4$ you can brute-force an optimal solution. What am I missing here?

Comment: @araomis The 2-Opt algorithm does not yield an approximation ratio of 2. In fact, it does not even yield a constant approximation ratio (even for metric TSP).

Comment: What is your definition of approximation ratio?

Comment: @araomis An algorithm for TSP has an approximation ratio of $r \geq 1$ if and only if $\mathrm{len} (T_{\mathrm{output}}) \leq r \cdot \mathrm{len}(T^*)$ for every instance where $T^*$ denotes an optimal tour. For general optimization problems this can be found on [wikipedia/Approximation_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm) under the section 'Performance guarantees'.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought would be the definition of approximation ratio you are using. Note that the 2-Opt algorithm guarantees that $len(T_{output}) \leq 2 len(T^*)$ though. Hence it yields an approximation ratio of $2$.

Comment: @araomis Where does this ratio come from?

Comment: Oh I am sorry for the confusion I caused. I see now that 2-Opt is not what I meant it is.

Comment: @araomis No worries. Now I see where the confusion comes from as well. 2-Opt and double-tree algorithm are two completely different algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those that stumble upon this question: The answer actually is quite simple. Let me explain.

Given an Instance $I = (K_n,w)$ of **metric** TSP, consider the following algorithm:

1. Construct an arbitrary Tour $T$ through $V$.
2. Return $T$.

I claim that this simple algorithm already achieves an approximation ratio of $n/2$: Let $T^*$ denote an optimal Tour. Let $e = (v,w)$ be an arbitrary edge of $T$. Note that $T^*$ is the disjoint union of two paths $P_1$ and $P_2$ where one is a $v$-$w$-Path and the other is a $w$-$v$-Path. By the triangle inequality we have
$$ w(e) \leq w(P_1) = \sum_{f \in E(P_1) } w(f)$$
and similarily $w(e) \leq w(P_2)$. Together with $w(T^*) = \sum_{f \in E(T^*)} w(f) = w(P_1) + w(P_2)$ it follows that
$$ 2w(e) \leq w(T^*).$$
Therefore
$$ w(T) = \sum_{e \in E(T)} w(e) \leq \sum_{e \in E(T)} \frac{1}{2}w(T^*) = \frac{n}{2}w(T^*),$$
which proves the claim.

My initial confusion came from the misunderstanding this approximation ratio would have something to do with the specific 2-Opt algorithm. However, as argued above, this is not the case and this approximation ratio is quite trivial to achieve.